# Publish only edited page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, upload, publish

Whenever I update a small part of my website I have to upload whole website again.
If i upload only edited part it throw me exception.

**The way I upload my website:**
For example if I have 4 pages (home, register, about me, contact me) and if I update home.aspx, I publish whole website in a local address, and then I compress it with `zip` format and upload it manually.

Is it possible to publish only updated part?

Comment: what version of visual studio that you use?

Comment: microsoft visual studio 2012 ultimate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to publish only a part of website, but what you can do is to choose **`Single-File Assembly`** build option ,by this you can get single assembly for your page.so intead of updating whole application you can update only the pages you change
 [read more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z38d5bzk.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What I always do when publish ASP.Net Webform project, I complate it with two steps. Maybe this way suitable for you.

1. When you use publishing tool on visual studio by selecting Build menu -> Publish, you can choose "File System" as "Publish Method", type your "Target Location", and select "Replace matching files with local copies". It mean the project will publish modified files only.
2. After publishing have done, Open defined "Target Location" using windows explore and sort by "Modified Date" and just copy newer modified files for each directory recursively to your server.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you build the website pages into dll. You can not published only the aspx. there are many other dll and compiled files in bin folder, we don't know which matches which aspx.
2. If you only edited the "view", i mean, the html and markup part of <%%> code, and no code behind (.aspx.cs) change, you can published only this aspx. But remember to set website as updatable in the publish dialog.

I suggest you to compile the aspx into one dll. according to @Buzz 's answer. Then, your aspx files would be only an empty file. All you need to do is upload only one dll to the bin folder.

Comment: haa haa, I can not stop laughing, I can't believe it two years ago I didn't know what is dll :))